# Why does svg path move when browser resizes?

Tags: html, svg

My code

```
<div class="map ">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1378 446" >
        <a href="#" onclick="openReserv(1)">
            <path class="part" d="m 352.16105,321.51686 -4.20122,20.51183 15.32209,3.2127 3.70696,-20.2647 z"
                                   fill="#4ddb73"  data-place-number="1" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="openReserv(2)">
            <path class="part" d="m 366.98888,324.97669 14.66009,2.93736 -3.58233,20.18336 -14.78472,-2.85602 z"
                                  fill="#4ddb73" data-place-number="2" />
        </a>
    </svg>
    <img src="~/img/floor14.png" alt="" class="im">
</div>
```

---

```
body {
}
.map{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
svg{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.part{
    opacity: .5;
}
.part:hover{
    transition: opacity .1s ease;
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When the browser is wide open, everything is fine. When I scale down the browser horizontally my rectangles slide out

[image]

To position elements on the page, I use the `bootstrap` library, namely the `Bootstrap grid`. How do I keep my parts in place when the browser is resized?

Comment: A snippet would be great

Comment: In your CSS, you set width and height of `svg` to 100%. This might override the viewBox dimensions of `<svg viewBox="...`. And therefore resize the svg content on smaller screens.

Comment: @mixable I removed from `Css`  `height: 100%;  width: 100%;` but it did not help

Comment: @gregor I think you also have to make sure, that the size of the `svg` is somehow scaled  and fits the size of the map when the screen is resized. In Bootstrap, `<img` (your floor14.png) will definitely scale to fit the size of its parent container (in the grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to the SVG

```
svg.banner { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```